How do I dynamically size HTML table column widths to the text in the "<th>" element?
I have a some data loaded into an HTML table. Each column of the table has a table header with text in it. I want each column to have a minimum width equal to length of that text (so that it doesn't overflow/wrap). How can I do this dynamically (preferably without JavaScript, just vanilla HTML/CSS)?
I've tried setting the width, min-width and max-width of the <th> elements in the CSS, it doesn't do anything.

@muhammad-aleem-hashmi, I have edited the question a bit. I don't think the back end is not relevant to the issue. I will try and make a simplified version of the issue and add it.

Please click [edit], then the button marked [<>]and provide a [mcve]

@MuhammadAleemHashmi we talk about an HTML table. This question has nothing to do with the backend or a database. As a matter of fact, an HTML table does not even require any kind of backend or database but could be hardcoded. In the end, it is purely a CSS question.

@tacoshy is right. Balraj Singh answered the question without any extra information. But I appreciate you trying to help me improve my question.
